# Viewing blob data-type in mysql

Tags: mysql, blob

I have downloaded a mysql table in text format from one our collaborator's. I have dumped the table into a table on mysql database on my machine successfully. The table was created using their sql file. SO they have some of the fields with `blob` data-type, and I am unable to view them in mysql. when I opened the same downloaded text file with csv I could see the fields with blob data-type with letters like `BC,ABD,BDS`. I do not understand why I am unable to view the fields in mysql. Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is sure you can not see the blob data directly when you view the table data from mysql. But i think when you click the edit link of particular row you might see the data but i'm not sure about this. If you are using any server script then you definitely gonna see data without any hassle using simple select query. Like

```
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME 

   // REGARDLESS OF COLUMN_NAME DATA TYPE
```